# google app engine 400 bad domain locked error : file not found

Tags: javascript, json, google-app-engine, uri, google-cloud-storage

Here I created a search functionality in javascript to pull the data from the bucket.
I have a bucket in the google cloud console which has a folder and a file in the folder

The issue here is that the folder name has spaces in database(cloud-bucket) so i cant figure out the issue

Bucket name: files-2016
Folder name: The Best Files
file name : abc_1.pdf

i tried 
encoding and also decoding the URI- because the URI shows %2025
applying trim and replace  - to try removing the spaces in the folder name

I'm not sure what is the error.
badLockedDomainRequest:code 400

Can any one help me :)
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and in particular http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.